# Excel lookup and insert formula

Tags: excel

I have a speadsheet with some data set out like the below.

In column C i want to lookup B and see if theres a match in the D column

[image]

If there is put A's value in C

[image]

I have tried common MATCH/LOOKUP formulas but I don't know how to insert column A, I dont have any experience in VBA and fear I need to use this

Any tips to aviod that be most helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH(D1,B:B,0),1))
```

Another way to skin a cat.

Comment: Be careful using this formula @Skin. Using `B:B` as a lookup range would slow down your workbook considerably on large datasets. Also `INDIRECT()` is volatile and will recalculate every time Excel recalculates, regardless of non-changed values in targeted cells. Just a headsup :)

Comment: @JvdV .. fair call, there are always reasons though.  I've worked with finance folk who fail to fill down/adjust formulas and then miss literally millions in budgets so I'd take a small performance hit over incorrect data any day of the week, hence the B:B approach and as for INDIRECT, it was just a different approach.  I have to admit, I was surprised to get the chocolates given the first answer was a shorter approach.  I was merely demonstrating another way to do it.  Your comments are welcome though.

Comment: Some performance hit or a few millions in budget lost....hm fair call :)

Answer (score 3):

Combining INDEX and MATCH allows you to search any column and then return the corresponding value in any column.

```
=INDEX($A$1:$A$5,MATCH(D1,$B$1:$B$5,0))
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to use "IFERROR" to avoid errors:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$5, MATCH(D1, $B$1:$B$5, 0)),"")
```